# Intercluster Communication in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have 2 clusters.

Cluster A which runs my main pods. Using ClusterIP as Service type.
Cluster B which runs additional pods. Also using ClusterIP as Service Type

I was wondering if there is anyway we can establish communication between one of the pods in Cluster A to another pod in Cluster B without exposing them as LoadBalancer type?

Currenly, I am using Ingress for user to Pod communication.

Thank You

Comment: Which CNI are you using? at least I know cilium offers cluster mesh for such use-cases, https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.10/gettingstarted/clustermesh/clustermesh/#gs-clustermesh

Comment: A pod should never talk to another pod. Pods are abstracted behind services so that Kubernetes can manage pod lifecycles for you. If you mean pod to service then by default, you cannot connect to services in other clusters except either by using nodeport service or load balancer service or another special networking provider.

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? Which Kubernetes solution are you using - bare metal or some cloud provider solution? Which LoadBalancer solution are you using? Are the clusters configured in the same network? Please add more details to your question about clusters setup and networking,